# AngularJS and listbox (select multiple)

Tags: angularjs

I have following:

```
<div>
<select multiple>
    <option ng-model="xss" ng-selected="u.selected" ng-repeat="u in xs" value="{{u.value}}">
        {{u.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

```
$scope.xss;
$scope.xs = [
    { id: 1, value: 'value 1', selected: false },
    { id: 2, value: 'value 2', selected: false },
    { id: 3, value: 'value 3', selected: false }
];
```

The select work fine, however the selected values is not bound to xss. How do you get selected items from a multiple select throug angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have the ng-model at the `<select>` statement instead of options as below,

```
<select multiple ng-model="xss" >
    <option ng-selected="u.selected" ng-repeat="u in xs" value="{{u.value}}">
      {{u.value}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3qKGKkA6G8bMdfwXdvwv)**